# Did the events of Convergence have any importance for The New 52?

Tags: dc, the-new-52

After I read **Justice League #50**, I noted that DC Comics *Rebirth* will be the continuation of *The New 52*. I did not get to read all of *The New 52*, but I thought that after *New 52: Future Ends*, the continuation of New 52 was *Convergence*. But it seems that I was wrong and it is just a limited series, a spin out.

So, did the events of *Convergence* have any importance for *The New 52*? I just saw a relation between ***Superman*** and ***Superman: Lois and Clark***.

Comment: I edited your question to be more grammatically correct, but I am not sure that I correctly understood what you were meaning to say in the last paragraph. Feel free to edit it if I changed the meaning of your question.

Comment: Oh man, my bad english! haha so, Lois and Clark was created in Post-Convergence and events of 52's Superman can be seen in Lois and Clark, then exists some connection between the titles, right? Any other title which was created post-convergence has a straight influence in 52?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr - Any changes put in place by Convergence were largely not used by writers, and will be subsumed and overridden by DC Rebirth.

This will likely be a somewhat confusing answer, I shall try to remain low-detail.

The big new point from Convergence was the idea that continuity in the books could be more malleable from an editorial sense.  Events from pre-52 eras were potentially useable.  Dan Didio tried to explain it in [this interview at Newsarama](http://www.newsarama.com/25288-infinite-earths-dan-didio-describes-post-convergence-dcu.html).

The Lois and Clark title features the Pre-52 Superman and Lois, the ones that were married.  They were saved from the cataclysm of Flashpoint by Telos, who placed them on his collection planet, the events of which were covered in Convergence.  We now learn that he, Lois, and their son (we shall tastefully leave the Larry Niven-esque discussions about that to the side) survived and made it to what is the prime DC-Earth, on which the current events of DC's titles were occurring. He is living incognito, allowing the Superman of this Earth to be Superman, only engaging in secret rescues.

Events in Superman and Justice League, and then filled in by Rebirth, will result in...let's say, a position change for this pre-52 Superman.

The Rebirth version of the DCU will have some big changes for many characters, most of which involve returning to a earlier, more "positive" take on them.  Ted Kord is back, and is working with Jaime Reyes, the new Blue Beetle.  Ryan Choi is alive, and Ray Palmer is back in the role of The Atom, and not the mad scientist of S.H.A.D.E.  The Legion of Super-Heroes appears to be back in play.

it's not quite a complete reboot, but enough changes are in play to make much of the recent history of many characters, both pre-Convergence and pst-new 52 up for some rewriting.

Comment: Basically, Convergence was a attempted to create a universe more malleable from an editorial sense, as you said, bringing old characters pre-new 52, they  weren't far with this because it was too much panned by readers right?

Comment: I think it didn't go far cause they didn't actually have any ideas to go with the new freedom. That's been (IMHO) the problem with the last few upheavals. They promise all these changes, and have few if any planned. The "Fifth age of Magic" for example  They seem to have gotten a solid plan in place with Rebirth, however.

Comment: I think that it would be a dead-end. Is there any titles post-convergence (besides Lois and Clark) has a straight relation with 52's titles ?

Comment: Telos (the Big Bad from Convergence) got a title where he as supposed to be going to other parallel Earths and fixing things. I think - I don't think I picked up a single issue.